# How can i get all objects in a column Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the column "D" in my spreadsheet. I would like to get all objects in the column and send an email to them. My script gets the firts user in the column and then loops it, it dosen't continue.

This i what i have:

```
function email(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   var email = dataSheet.getRange(2, 5);
    var email2 = email.getValue();


  for (var i = 0; i < email2.length; ++i) {
    // Get a row object
    var rowData = email2[i];  

 MailApp.sendEmail(rowData emailSubject, emailText);
    Logger.log(email2); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you selected only one cell, so you are making a loop in a single element...

try this way :

```
function email(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var emails = dataSheet.getRange('D2:D').getValues();


  for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; ++i) {
    // Get a row object
    var rowData = emails[i][0];  
    if(rowData!=''){
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData emailSubject, emailText);// I assume emailSubject and emailText are defined in your real code...
    }
    Logger.log(emails[i]); 
  }
}
```